# Select value in Xelement within Xelement?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

For a Webradio app in windows Phone, i'm trying to read an XML file with the data, but i'm having a problem with a specific field. The XML File looks like this:

```
<brands xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <brandgroup>
        <brand>
            <code>blabla</code>
            <name>blabla</name>
            <logo>blabla</logo>
            <websiteurl>blabla</websiteurl>
            <audiostreams>
                <audiostream streamurl="www.1.mp3" codec="mp3" streamrate="low"/>
                <audiostream streamurl="www.2.mp3" codec="mp3" streamrate="med" default="true"/>
                <audiostream streamurl="www.3.mp3" codec="mp3" streamrate="high"/>
            </audiostreams>
        </brand>
        <brand>
        </brand>
    </brandgroup>
    other 'brandgroups' with other 'brand'
</brand>
```

---

With the next Code i'm capable of getting the Name, Code, and Website into and object of Class Station for every brand inside every brandgroup.

---

```
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("netten.xml");
var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("brand") 
           select new Station
           {
               Name = (string)query.Element("name"),
               Code = (int)query.Element("code"),
               Website = (string)query.Element("websiteurl"), 
           };
```

---

However, I can't find a way to get the audiostream. There is the 'audiostreams' element wich has 3 child 'audiostream' elements, where i need the 'streamurl'.

Best would be to store the 3 streamurls so i could change the quality later on. Then i should need to have a field in Class Station:

```
String[] streamurls = {www.1.mp3, www.2.mp3, www.3.mp3};
```

and store the 3 streamurls in there to select later on. I've tried some things that are posted here related to XML, Attribute and XElement, but i can't get it to work.

Is there anyone out there that knows a way?

Btw I don't really get how to highlight code and stuff here, I hope it works, otherwse I'm really sorry...

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want just the URLs, you can do something like (assuming the is a property of type `IEnumerable<string>` (or `string[]`) called `StreamUrls` on `Station`):

```
from brand in loadedData.Descendants("brand") 
select new Station
{
    Name = (string)brand.Element("name"),
    Code = (int)brand.Element("code"),
    Website = (string)brand.Element("websiteurl"), 
    StreamUrls = brand.Element("audiostreams")
              .Elements("audiostream")
              .Attributes("streamurl")
              .Select(a => a.Value)
              .ToArray()
}
```

If you want to get other information from the `audiostream` elements, declare a class like:

```
class Stream
{
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Codec { get; set; }
    public string Rate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }
}
```

And the query would then look like:

```
from brand in loadedData.Descendants("brand") 
select new Station
{
    Name = (string)brand.Element("name"),
    Code = (int)brand.Element("code"),
    Website = (string)brand.Element("websiteurl"), 
    Streams =
        (from stream in brand.Element("audiostreams").Elements("audiostream")
        select new Stream
        {
            Url = (string)stream.Attribute("streamurl"),
            Codec = (string)stream.Attribute("codec"),
            Rate = (string)stream.Attribute("streamrate"),
            IsDefault = (string)stream.Attribute("default") == "true"
        }).ToArray()
}
```

(If `Codec` and `Rate` can only have certain values, expressing them as an `enum` would be better than `string`.)

Comment: I never tried doing another query when selecting the new Station.  That's what I get for trying to solve a problem at 3 AM when I should be asleep.  Nice solution :)

Comment: that worked like a charm, thank you very much! Right now it's still a string value, making it an enum is for after i get the app actually working :p

Answer (score 0):

Hope it is useful

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load("netten.xml");
        var data = from query in loadedData.Descendants("brand")
                   group query by new { A = query.Element("name"), B = query.Element("code"), C = query.Element("websiteurl"), D = query.Element("audiostreams") } into g
                   select new
                   {
                       Name = g.Key.A + "",
                       Code = g.Key.B + "",
                       Website = g.Key.C + "",

                       AudioStreams = g.Key.D.Elements("audiostream")
                                                .Attributes("streamurl")
                                                .Select(x => x.Value)
                                                .ToArray()

                   };


        foreach (var x in data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Name);
            Console.WriteLine(x.Code);
            Console.WriteLine(x.Website);

            foreach (var url in x.AudioStreams)
                Console.WriteLine(url);
        }


        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

The xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<brands xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <brandgroup>
    <brand>
      <code>blabla</code>
      <name>blabla</name>
      <logo>blabla</logo>
      <websiteurl>blabla</websiteurl>
      <audiostreams>
        <audiostream streamurl="www.1.mp3" codec="mp3" streamrate="low"/>
        <audiostream streamurl="www.2.mp3" codec="mp3" streamrate="med" default="true"/>
        <audiostream streamurl="www.3.mp3" codec="mp3" streamrate="high"/>
      </audiostreams>
    </brand>
  </brandgroup>
  <brandgroup>
    <brand>
      <code>blabla2</code>
      <name>blabla2</name>
      <logo>blabla</logo>
      <websiteurl>blabla2</websiteurl>
      <audiostreams>
        <audiostream streamurl="www.4.mp3" codec="mp3" streamrate="low"/>
        <audiostream streamurl="www.5.mp3" codec="mp3" streamrate="med" default="true"/>
        <audiostream streamurl="www.6.mp3" codec="mp3" streamrate="high"/>
      </audiostreams>
    </brand>
  </brandgroup>
</brands>
```

Comment: I don't the name of the station should be `<name>blabla</name>`, which is what your code prints.

Comment: This is only a sample , I means u can set your unique item to group by key ... and then get to streamurl  easy and safe...